# AppStore Review: Is there any way to get to another reviewer?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

Is there a way to resubmit an iOS app for review so that it will be verified by another Apple employee?

Apple rejects our app for the third time because of spam (point 4.3 of AppStore Review Guidelines), but we don't agree with that. Our app has a lot of features that similar apps don't have. We want to get some additional information about the reason, but Apple always sends us a sample answer without any details.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to guarantee a different reviewer.

It is highly likely that each review is documented internally, with future reviewers examining the application's past before starting a new review. Thus problems or concerns raised before, will be raised again.

## Contact Apple Developer

Only Apple can help you. [Contact Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) and ask them for more information about the rejection. Phoning Apple may result in a more detailed answer and start a conversation about eventually being accepted.

Regrettably Apple's reviews can feel capricious; this is a cost of being in Apple's App Store.